# SQL Server : merge two rows into one

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I wrote the this T-SQL query:

```
SELECT 
    B.[Year], E.[Description] as GLClass, 
    D.Code, D.[GLDescription], 
    SUM(A.Jan) AS Jan, 
    SUM(A.Feb) AS Feb, 
    SUM(A.Mar) AS Mar, 
    SUM(A.Apr) AS Apr
FROM
    GeneralLedgers A 
INNER JOIN
    Years B ON A.YearID = B.ID
INNER JOIN
    CostCenters C ON A.CostCenterID = C.ID
INNER JOIN
    GLCodes D ON A.GLCodeID = D.ID 
INNER JOIN
    GLClassificationTypes E ON D.GLClassificationTypeID = E.ID
WHERE 
    A.YearID = '13' 
GROPU BY 
    B.[Year], D.Code, E.[Description], D.[GLDescription]
ORDER BY 
    D.Code, E.[Description]
```

It outputs this result:

[image]

I want to combine "Freight-in (Go) and Freight Savings" row into a single row and  sum the value from column Jan, Feb, Mar, Apr.  I was trying to used the Case When clause on the  "Code" column to look for '401040110' and '441010300' but still can't figure it out.

How can this be accomplish?

Comment: Just add case statement for both code and description to both select and group by -- or make a small table for this conversion if you have other items that you need to combine

Comment: I'd recommend using **more meaningful** table aliases than just A, B, C, D etc. - using `Y` for `Years`, `CC` for `CostCenters`, `GL` for `GeneralLedger` etc. would make your query just **so much more readable** and more easily understandable.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Convert one of the 2 rows into the other for your groupings logic and the rest of the aggregation should work on top of that seamlessly.

```
SELECT B.[Year]
    ,E.[Description] AS GLClass
    ,case when D.Code = '441010300' then '401040110' else D.Code END    Code
    ,case when D.Code = '441010300' then 'Freight-in (Go)' else  D.[GLDescription] end [GLDescription]
    ,Sum(A.Jan) AS Jan
    ,Sum(A.Feb) AS Feb
    ,Sum(A.Mar) AS Mar
    ,Sum(A.Apr) AS Apr
FROM GeneralLedgers A
INNER JOIN Years B ON A.YearID = B.ID
INNER JOIN CostCenters C ON A.CostCenterID = C.ID
INNER JOIN GLCodes D ON A.GLCodeID = D.ID
INNER JOIN GLClassificationTypes E ON D.GLClassificationTypeID = E.ID
WHERE A.YearID = '13'
GROUP BY B.[Year]
    , case when D.Code = '441010300' then '401040110' else D.Code END   
    , E.[Description]
    , case when D.Code = '441010300' then 'Freight-in (Go)' else  D.[GLDescription] end
ORDER BY 3,2
```

Comment: Thank you very much...I couldn't understand  the Group by part when I was trying. Thank you again..